# Android app not retrieving data from firebase after release on play store

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, proguard, release

**App behaviour in play store**

-Not retrieving data from firebase

-When i change variable in textbox, i expect new elements to be displayed.It works correctly in debug mode but crashes after play store deployment

**What i tried**

**-Play store SHA keys**

```
-Put signingKeys of play console in firebase
-Put both debug and release keys of android app in firebase, with later being added after                    
 creating
```

**-Proguard**

-made  minifyEnabled false - no change

-Change in data class (was written in kotlin)

```
     @IgnoreExtraProperties
     @Keep
     data class Name{
         val property1: String = "",
         val property2: Int = 0
     }
```

-Proguard file

```
    -keepattributes Signature
    -keepattributes *Annotation*
    -keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
    -keep class org.apache.** { *; }
    -keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
    -keepnames class javax.servlet.** { *; }
    -keepnames class org.ietf.jgss.** { *; }
    -dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
    -dontwarn org.joda.time.**
    -dontwarn org.shaded.apache.**
    -dontwarn org.ietf.jgss.**


    -keep class com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
    -keepnames class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
    -keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
    -keepclassmembers class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
    -dontusemixedcaseclassnames
    -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
    -verbose
```

build.gradle

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-  optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

Even after all these changes,i am unable to retrieve data from firebase